# How to use \csname\endcsname in LaTeX3 way?

Tags: programming, latex3

I have some part or code made in `LaTeX2e` way. I been to rewrite it in `LaTeX3` way, but I have no idea how to do this. More expanation in MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{100}
% ======== Common way =======================
\def\daycell#1#2{\csname dc#1#2\endcsname}
\daycell{1}{2}
\expandafter\def\csname dc12\endcsname{\themycounter}

% =========== The LaTeX3 way =======================
\ExplSyntaxOn


\cs_new:Npn \DayCell {#1#2} {\cs:w dc#1#2 \cs_end:} % I have no idea


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\daycell{1}{2}

\end{document}
```

---

Added for clarifying

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \sergiokapone_daycell:nn #1 #2
  {
    \use:c { dc #1 #2 }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \sergiokapone_set_daycell:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \cs_set:cpn { dc #1 #2 } { #3 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \SetDayCell { mmm }
  {
    \sergiokapone_set_daycell:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \DayCell { m m }
  {
    \sergiokapone_daycell:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\DeclareDocumentCommand\Replicate{ m    m }{%
    \prg_replicate:nn {#1} {#2} 
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% ======== desired result (it is work) ========
% Temporary commented
%---- Here \SetDayCell{i}{j}{some number}
%\SetDayCell{1}{1}{1}
%\SetDayCell{1}{2}{2}
%\SetDayCell{1}{3}{3}
%\SetDayCell{1}{4}{4}
%\SetDayCell{1}{5}{5}
% I get what I want  1 2 3 4 5

% ======= I want to just replicate example from above ===
% But it work incorrect
\newcounter{C}
\setcounter{C}{1}
\Replicate{5}{
\SetDayCell{1}{\theC}{\theC}
\stepcounter{C}
}
% I get 6 6 6 6 6

% ==== cell's filling ==== 
\newcounter{var}
\setcounter{var}{1}
\Replicate{5}{
\DayCell{1}{\thevar}
\stepcounter{var}
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\use:c{dc#1#2}`

Comment: You need to expand `\theC` or `\thevar`. I added the relevant code to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to provide a variant of your `\DayCell` function that uses a `:c` argument, if it were only a single argument which should be turned into a control sequence.

Also please note that the arguments in a `\cs_new:Npn` statement are not allowed to contain braces (it's syntax is more or less the one of TeX's `\def`).

Your internal functions created with `\cs_new:Npn` and similar should always contain the types of arguments as part of their name, so for a macro that takes two braced arguments you should have the a name such as `\<module>_<name>:nn`, the functions should always follow that naming scheme `\<module>_<name>:<args>`.

Also, if not absolutely necessary, you should use the higher level functions to turn something into a macro name, so only use `\cs:w` and `\cs:end` if absolutely necessary, e.g., because begin and end are in two different macros, else you should use `\use:c`.

Also `\cs_new:Npn` and similar should only be used for internal functions, document/user level functions are to be defined using `\NewDocumentCommand` or similar.

Turning all of the above into some code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \sergiokapone_daycell:nn #1 #2
  {
    \use:c { dc #1 #2 }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \sergiokapone_set_daycell:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \cs_set:cpn { dc #1 #2 } { #3 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \SetDayCell { mmm }
  {
    \sergiokapone_set_daycell:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \DayCell { m m }
  {
    \sergiokapone_daycell:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\SetDayCell{1}{2}{100}
\DayCell{1}{2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: likes I found the `\SetDayCell` does not change counter #3 in loop

Comment: It doesn't use a counter in my answer, it just defines some macro (`dc#1#2`) to expand to the third argument, if you want that to be a counter you'd do `\SetDayCell{1}{2}{\thecounter}`.

Comment: @ Skillmon likes topanswers.xyz Yes I mean the such construction `\SetDayCell{1}{2}{\thecounter}` work incorrect in a loop

Comment: @sergiokapone I can't help without seeing code in that case.

Comment: I had added the code for clarifying in my post

Comment: @sergiokapone that's the issue @egreg has already explained. You could use `\cs_set:cpx { dc #1 #2 } { #3 }` instead in the definition of `\sergiokapone_set_daycell:nnn`, that should work.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with your code. Let me first analyze the “traditional” code.

If you do `\expandafter\def\csname dc#1#2\endcsname{\themycounter}` you ***won't*** get 100 after doing `\daycell{1}{2}`, unless the value of `mycounter` has not changed in the meantime. You should use `\edef`.

As regards to the `expl3` implementation, this seems to call for a property list.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\setdaycell}{mmm}
 {
  \sergio_daycell_set:nne { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\daycell}{mm}
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \l_sergio_daycell_prop { #1#2 }
 }

\prop_new:N \l_sergio_daycell_prop

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sergio_daycell_set:nnn
 {
  \prop_put:Nnn \l_sergio_daycell_prop { #1#2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \sergio_daycell_set:nnn { nne }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{mycounter}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{mycounter}{100}

\setdaycell{1}{2}{\themycounter}

\setcounter{mycounter}{42}

\daycell{1}{2}

\end{document}
```

This will print 100.

---

After seeing your example, it is obvious you have some problem with expansion, similar to what's described in the second paragraph above.

Here's how you can do it by forcing expansion at the appropriate time.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%%% for the example
\NewDocumentCommand{\replicate}{mm}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
%%%%%%%%

\NewDocumentCommand{\setdaycell}{mmm}
 {
  \sergio_daycell_set:nne { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\daycell}{mm}
 {
  \prop_item:Ne \l_sergio_daycell_prop { #1#2 }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn { Nx }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { Ne }
\prop_new:N \l_sergio_daycell_prop

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sergio_daycell_set:nnn
 {
  \prop_put:Nxn \l_sergio_daycell_prop { #1#2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \sergio_daycell_set:nnn { nne }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcounter{C}
\setcounter{C}{1}
\replicate{5}{%
  \setdaycell{1}{\theC}{\theC}%
  \stepcounter{C}%
}
% I get 6 6 6 6 6

% ==== cell's filling ==== 
\newcounter{var}
\setcounter{var}{1}
\replicate{5}{%%
  \daycell{1}{\thevar}%
  \stepcounter{var} % <- space is wanted
}

\end{document}
```

This will correctly print “1 2 3 4 5”

Comment: Thank you! It is hard to understand where I need expand some macro.

Comment: @sergiokapone You don't want to store `\theC`, but the *contents* of `\theC`.

Comment: Now I see. But what if I want to expand only \thecounter? I have a situation like `\bfseries\thecounter` or `\cellcolor{red}\thecounter`, the `\bfseries` do not need to be expanded, but \thecounter does.

Comment: @sergiokapone Do you really want to store formatting information? Anyway, the strategy for coping with this depends on the *real* problem you're facing.

Comment: Yes, maybe it is bad idea. My base idea was just indexing table cell, i.e assign two numbers ij for cell, I thaught it is possible to do via \csname. Using index I want put some formatted information in cell. In my case is a day of week.

Comment: @sergiokapone It's better to ask a question with the details.

Comment: I ask another question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526410/how-to-index-table-cells