# How to index table cells?

Tags: tables, programming

I have a table. I need to put some value (of a counter) in it cell and apply some format to cell depending on position of cell. For this reasons I need a  indexing a cell.

I was used code for indexing:

```
\def\Cell#1#2{\csname dc#1#2\endcsname}
```

and code for putting information in cell

```
\def\SetCell#1#2#3{%
\expandafter\xdef\csname dc#1#2\endcsname{#3}
}
```

But such code expands #3, and this is good, because I want use counter as #3, but if I want format cell (say put cell color, or change font) I get a problem due to expansion.  For example, I wand decorate cell 2,2 in yellow color and bold font in this cell has counter number 8. So my question:

> Is there a good indexing method to pass formatted data to a cell,
>   including counter values?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\def\Cell#1#2{\csname dc#1#2\endcsname}

\def\SetCell#1#2#3{%
\expandafter\edef\csname dc#1#2\endcsname{#3}
}


\begin{document}


\newcounter{i}
\setcounter{i}{1}
\newcounter{j}
\setcounter{j}{1}

\romannumeral\xintreplicate{2}{%
\setcounter{j}{1}
\romannumeral\xintreplicate{8}{%
\SetCell{\thei}{\thej}{\thej}%
\stepcounter{j}%
}
\stepcounter{i}%
}


\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c||c|c|}
    \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{1}%     
                        & \Cell{1}{1} & \Cell{1}{2} & \Cell{1}{3} & \Cell{1}{4} \\ \hhline{|~||*2{-}*2{-}}
                        & \Cell{1}{5} & \Cell{1}{6} & \Cell{1}{7} & \Cell{1}{8} \\ \hhline{*3{-}*2{-}}
        \multirow{3}{*}{2}%     
                        & \Cell{2}{1} & \Cell{2}{2} & \Cell{2}{3} & \Cell{2}{4} \\ \hhline{|~||*2{-}*2{-}}
                        & \Cell{2}{5} & \Cell{2}{6} & \Cell{2}{7} & \Cell{2}{8} \\ \hhline{*3{-}*2{-}}
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

Desired result is table (Calendar) for a desired year with months started from 9 to 12 or 2 to 5 (complete code [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13MZeoxmr4zi5F6Z2LwJu6g9-cPBuvByM)):

[image]

Comment: There's no information about what formatting you'd want to use for cells. You're just setting cells without any formatting.

Comment: @egreg I meant, say I want decorate cell 2,2 as bold font and yellow color if value of counter in cell is, say 8 .

Comment: Then the way you use in the example for filling in values is completely misleading.

Comment: @egreg Yes, this is bad algorithm, may be you  suggest the best?

Comment: This is the first thing that crossed my mind, and it worked fine until I had to format the cell.

Comment: I guess that you have a *real* table to show, not just one filled with dummy numbers.

Comment: @egreg I had already in post. Such table was generated by described algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the [luaprogtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/luaprogtable?lang=en) package, which is exactly designed for this kind of scenarios. Setting a cell can be easily done by using `\LPTSetCell`.

The following code generates the table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{luaprogtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
% create a new table named calendar
% which has 14 rows, 15 columns
\LPTNewTable{calendar}{15}{|c||*{7}{c|}|*{7}{c|}}[nrows=14, default after line=\cline{2-15}]
% bind current table
\LPTSetCurrentTable{calendar}
% set before line for row 1
\LPTSetRowProp{1}{before line=\hline}
% set double lines
\LPTSetRowProp{1,2,5, 8, 11}{after line=\hhline{*{15}{=}}}
\LPTSetRowProp{-1}{after line=\hline}

% set some individual cells
\LPTSetCell{1,1}{2020}
\LPTSetCell{1,2}[1,7]{\multicolumn{7}{c||}{\bfseries I Week}}
\LPTSetCell{1,9}[1,7]{\multicolumn{7}{c|}{\bfseries II Week}}
\LPTSetCell{2,1}{Day}
\LPTSetCell{3,1}[3,1]{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{February}}}
\LPTSetCell{6,1}[3,1]{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{March}}}
\LPTSetCell{9,1}[3,1]{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{April}}}
\LPTSetCell{12,1}[3,1]{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{May}}}


\ExplSyntaxOn
% fill day names
\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa,Su}
\int_step_inline:nn {7} {
    \exp_args:Nxx \LPTSetCell {2,\int_eval:n {#1+1}} {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}}
    \exp_args:Nxx \LPTSetCell {2,\int_eval:n {#1+8}} {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}}
}

% function to fill days
% #1: start number
% #2: end number
% #3: offset
% #4: filling row index
\cs_set:Npn \fill_calendar:nnnn #1#2#3#4 {
    % stores current row
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {#4}
    % current column index
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int {2 + #3}
    \int_step_inline:nnn {#1} {#2} {
        \exp_args:Nxx \LPTSetCell {\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int, \int_use:N \l_tmpb_int} {##1}
        \int_incr:N \l_tmpb_int
        \int_compare:nNnT {\l_tmpb_int} = {14+2} {
            \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int {2}
        }
    }
}

\fill_calendar:nnnn {3}{29}{0}{3}
\fill_calendar:nnnn {2}{31}{0}{6}
\fill_calendar:nnnn {1}{30}{2}{9}
\fill_calendar:nnnn {1}{31}{4}{12}
\ExplSyntaxOff

{
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\LPTUseTable
}
\end{document}
```